# how i can retrieve gender and phone number and birthdate from signInWithGoogle flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

How can I retrieve the gender and phone number and birthdate?

```
Future<UserCredential> signInWithGoogle() async {

  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn(scopes: [
    'email',
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/profile.agerange.read"
  ]).signIn();

  
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
      await googleUser?.authentication;
 
  final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
  );

   
  
  return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
}
```

how i can retrieve gender  and phone number and birthdate
thanks for any help
my code is

Comment: You need to go though the google people api

Comment: check example  pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in/example
i don't know how i can retrieve from api  gender or  birthdate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the data for the scopes you requested, you can check the [`scopes` property](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_sign_in/latest/google_sign_in/GoogleSignIn/scopes.html) of the [`GoogleSignIn`](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_sign_in/latest/google_sign_in/GoogleSignIn-class.html) object.

There's an example of this in the [pub.dev example tab for the package](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in/example). Then after the call where the user authorizes access to these scopes, they should be set on the `scopes` property I linked above.

Comment: thanks 
this  example    not show anything i can  get name   without  any issue from UserCredential 
but i think  this package not  stable 
 show "Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null"  sometimes  
do you know this issue

Comment: i set  scop
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.birthday.read',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.gender.read',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read'

but  i  can't retrieve anything 
show No contacts to display

Comment: I haven't used that API myself, but it sounds like the API call is successful and just doesn't have any results (vs the API call not being allowed, which I would expect an error for).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will help, I tried to get phone numbers and user information. I have connected the [People API](https://developers.google.com/people/). My main mistake, I forgot to call this API after getting the GoogleSignInAccount user.

```
https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=phoneNumbers,emailAddresses,names,addresses
```

The simple example how to get properties:

```
const List<String> scopes = <String>[
  'email',
  'profile',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/user.phonenumbers.read',
  'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
];

GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
  scopes: scopes,
);

class SignInWithGoogleButton extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignInWithGoogleButton({super.key});

  @override
  State<SignInWithGoogleButton> createState() => _SignInWithGoogleButtonState();
}

class _SignInWithGoogleButtonState extends State<SignInWithGoogleButton> {
  GoogleSignInAccount? _currentUser;

  final _socialAuthService = SocialAuthService();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged
        .listen((GoogleSignInAccount? account) async {
      unawaited(_handleGetData(account!));
    });
  }

  Future<void> _handleSignIn() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    } catch (error) {
      print({'error': error});
    }
  }

 
  Future<void> _handleGetData(GoogleSignInAccount user) async {
    final http.Response response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
      'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/me?personFields=phoneNumbers,emailAddresses,names,addresses'),
      headers: await user.authHeaders,
    );

 
    print('People API ${response.statusCode} response: ${response.body}');
    
    final Map<String, dynamic> data =
        json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _handleSignIn,
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        height: 44,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
          border: Border.all(
            color: ProjectColors.grayscale300,
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SvgPicture.asset(
              'assets/svg/logo-google.svg',
              semanticsLabel: 'lock content',
              width: 18,
              height: 18,
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 11),
            Text(
              'Continue with Google',
              style: defaultTheme.textTheme.labelLarge?.copyWith(
                height: 1.2,
                color: ProjectColors.grayscale600,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you do everything right, you will get this JSON

```
{
  "resourceName": "people/117150691545051930411",
  "etag": "%EgUBCy43PxoEAQIFBw==",
  "phoneNumbers": [{...}],
  "emailAddresses": [{...}],
  "names": [{...}],
}
```

https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get - API link with sandbox, here I made the correct request

https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in/example - here I once again looked at the _handleGetContact and _pickFirstNamedContact functions

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the gender, phone number, and birthdate because the [GoogleSignInAccount](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_sign_in/latest/google_sign_in/GoogleSignInAccount-class.html) doesn't contain such fields. The only fields that are present are, the [displayName](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_sign_in/latest/google_sign_in/GoogleSignInAccount/displayName.html), [email](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_sign_in/latest/google_sign_in/GoogleSignInAccount/email.html), [id](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_sign_in/latest/google_sign_in/GoogleSignInAccount/id.html), and [photoUrl](https://pub.dev/documentation/google_sign_in/latest/google_sign_in/GoogleSignInAccount/photoUrl.html).

Comment: thanks for help  by  i think  i can retrieve by  
https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in/example
but i don't  know how i can retrive gender or birthdate